# Dynamically update post title in admin page

Tags: posts, jquery, javascript, title

I have a textarea in admin post page when creating new post, that's title:

```
<textarea id="post-title-0" class="editor-post-title__input" placeholder="Add title" rows="1" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 94px;">vbhgfhfgh</textarea>
```

I want to update title on the fly using jQuery. I tried

```
$('#post-title-0').val('some value');
$('#post-title-0').text('some value');
```

I also tried using plain javascript.

`val()` updates title but when I click on title it is being erased. Is there anyway to update title via JS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The block editor is restoring back the title that was last saved (or typed manually into the textarea), so with the block editor, you can change the title dynamically using this code:

```js
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( { title: 'Title here' } )
```

PS: You should make sure your JS file has the `wp-editor`, `wp-edit-post` or `wp-data` as part of the dependencies.

### UPDATE

Here are the resources which helped me identify the above solution/code:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/#dispatch
- https://riad.blog/2018/06/07/efficient-client-data-management-for-wordpress-plugins
- https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/editor/src/components/post-title/index.js (the React component which setups the title textarea / UI)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll test it out :)

Comment: Sure, take your time. :)

Comment: It worked. yeeeey :D
BTW where did you find that info, is it anywhere on WP official page?

Comment: I decided to update the answer with the resources which helped me. I hope that helps you. ;)

Comment: Thank you for this.